# Calling javascript function from Rshiny with parameter Passing

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to Call javascript function from Rshiny.But could not able to do that.
Here is my script.

```
Serevr.R

fluidRow(
        tags$input(id=paste(change_actionButton,"-ID",sep=""),type="button", 
                    class="btn  mubuttn action-button btn-large btn-primary", 
                    HTML('Change'),onClick="dis('"+name+"')"))

      )

event.js
function dis(name){
alert(name)
}
```

I want to pass name,which is a variable from **R.Tell** me how to send name to **event.js**

Comment: Got the result:
The solution is 
onClick = HTML(paste("dis(\"",key,"\",\"",value,"\")",sep=""))